# More SMTP accounts for Mail in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

Is is possible to set more accounts for Mail in Laravel 4? If I'm right, for the Mail facade I can set only one SMTP account in app/config/mail.php file. But in my application I need to send emails from two different SMTP accounts. I’m rewriting it from Symfony framework and as Symfony uses plain Swiftmailer it is very easy to set separate account credentials for every  action. How could I do the same in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This let's me change mail instantiation:

```
$transport = SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 25);
$transport->setEncryption('tls');
$transport->setUsername('ladislav@gmail.com');
$transport->setPassword('xxxxxx');
$swift = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
Mail::setSwiftMailer($swift);
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to change? If its just the address or name see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L83), you can change the swiftmailer properties with [that command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L404)

Comment: You can use SwiftMailer directly in Laravel too

Comment: Laravel uses SwiftMailer I know... For the record: You would get the Swiftmailer instance without the Mailerinstance like this: `App::make('swift.mailer');`

Comment: If I use App::make('swift.mailer'); how should I create instance of Swift_Message?

Comment: You don't have to create it yourself, edit the instance